# Place individual items from a data.frame/matrix into a new data.frame organized by groups

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I have data that basically looks like this (the 2nd and 3rd line is just to get it into a 1 column format, which is how my original data is formatted):

```
temp1 <- c("AB","CC","bC","aB","Ba","ac","Bb","Ac")
temp2 <- t(temp1)
dat1 <- t(temp2)
```

I want to take this data and place it into a new data.frame that looks like this:

```
   Red Blue Yellow Purple Green Orange
1   Ac  aB    CC     AB           ac                 
2       Ba    bC                               
3       Bb
```

with elements from the original list being placed into color columns based on criteria like:

```
AA = Red
AB = Purple
Bc = Blue
etc, etc, etc
```

The only difference is that my list contains 50+ types (AA,Aa,aA,etc).  I can think of extremely inefficient and long-coded ways to do this, but I'm hoping someone has a simple or elegant solution that I've missed.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a data.frame seems like an incorrect data structure to store the results. Data.frames expect rectangular data where each row has data for each of the columns. A list seems like a better choice in this case. I would create a named reassignment vector like so

```
reassign<-c(Ac="Red",aB="Blue",Ba="Blue", Bb="Blue", 
    CC="Yellow",bC="Yellow", AB="Purple", ac="Orange")
```

And you can split your data with

```
split(temp1, reassign[temp1])
```

which returns a list that looks like

```
$Blue
[1] "aB" "Ba" "Bb"

$Orange
[1] "ac"

$Purple
[1] "AB"

$Red
[1] "Ac"

$Yellow
[1] "CC" "bC"
```

Comment: I did a small test and it looks like this will work - thanks!  I'll accept it as the answer after a full test. :)